# Can't find the error in minimum difference between two numbers on array in C

Tags: c, arrays

So I'm really new to programming. I need to write a program that, if I give it any array of integers, it'll be able to find the two numbers closest to each other, and then give the difference between those two numbers. Also, the first number must be the number of integers that are going to be in the array.

So for example, I give it 3 1 4 8. The first 3 means that there will be three integers, so it must find the closest two numbers between those three. In this case, it's 4 - 1 = 3, so the output should be 3, but when I write it it gives me 16.

This is what I have, and I don't know what's wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int n, i;

    printf("Write numbers here\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int st[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&st[i]);

    int a, b, str[n*n], minimum, c;

    /* here I'll make a new array, and its elements will be all the
      differences between all the elements of the previous one */

    for(a=0;a<n;a++)
        for(b=0+a*n;b<n;b++) {
            if(st[b-a*n]==st[a])
                str[b]=32000;
            else 
                str[b]=abs(st[b-a*n]-st[a]);
        }

    // here I'll find the smallest element on the last made array

    minimum = str[0];

    for(c=0;c<n*n;c++)
    {
        if(str[c]<minimum); 
        {
            minimum=str[c];
        }
    }
    printf("%d", minimum);

    return 0;

}
```

Edit: I tried to fix it with your answers but it still doesn't work. 
New code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int n, i;

    printf("Write numbers here\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int st[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&st[i]);

    int a, b, minimum;

    minimum = st[0];

    for(a=0;a<n;a++)
        for(b=0;b<n;b++) {
            if((st[b] != st[a]) && (abs(st[b]-st[a]))<minimum) 
                minimum = abs(st[b]-st[a]);
        }

    printf("%d", minimum);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit 2: Ok, I fixed it now. Thanks a lot ^^

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {

    int n, i;

    printf("write numbers here\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int st[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&st[i]);

    int a, b, minimum;

    minimum = INT_MAX;

    for(a=0;a<n;a++)
        for(b=a+1;b<n;b++) {
            if((abs(st[b]-st[a]))<minimum)
                minimum = abs(st[b]-st[a]);
        }

    printf("%d", minimum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger, used debug print statements or attempted any other way to debug the problem yourself?

Comment: In general, you should check the result from `scanf()` and other input functions to ensure that they got the input you expected/hoped.

Comment: Your for loops are all messed up.  Start your for b loop from a+1.  And throw away the str array, you are making this way too complicated.  You should be checking abs( st[b]-st[a]) and comparing it with a minimum value as you go through the loops.

Comment: You shouldn't start with `minimum = st[0]`, but with something like `minimum = INT_MAX`. Also, by comparing `st[a] != st[b]` you omit the case when the same item is in the list twice. Instead you can just write the inner loop as `for (b=a+1; b<n; b++)`, no need to compare elements you have already compared again.

Comment: Yep, it worked, thank you very much ^^